# Adding or subtracting a variable from a running total based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a simple trivia game. What I have below prompts the user and displays a question in an interactive way.

I want to add in a "score" feature. Whenever I try to initialize a "count" at 0 or something similar within my `Question` class, and increment by the value stored in `value`, `count` stays at 0. I'm having trouble here. Ideally I want to print the score after the user answers each question. Adding `self.value` to `count` if correct, and subtracting otherwise.

```
import random

class Question(object):
def __init__(self, question, answer, value):
    self.question = question
    self.answer = answer
    self.value = value



def ask(self):
    print (self.question + "?")
    count = 0
    response = input().strip()
    if response in self.answer:
        x = random.randint(0,3)
        print (positives[x])
        print ("Answer is" + " " + self.answer)


    else:
        y = random.randint(0,3)
        print (negatives[y])
        print ("Answer is" + " " + self.answer)



question_answer_value_tuples = [('This author made a University of Virginia law professor the    protagonist of his 2002 novel "The Summons"',
'(John) Grisham']
#there are a few hundred of these. This is an example that I read into Question. List of tuples I made from a jeopardy dataset. 

positives = ["Correct!", "Nice Job", "Smooth", "Smarty"]
negatives = ["Wrong!", "Think Again", "Incorrect", "So Sorry" ]


questions = []
for (q,a,v) in question_answer_value_tuples:
    questions.append(Question(q,a,v))

print ("Press any key for a new question, or 'quit' to quit. Enjoy!")
for question in questions:
    print ("Continue?")
    choice = input()
    if choice in ["quit", "no", "exit", "escape", "leave"]:
        break
    question.ask()
```

I want to add something like

```
count = 0
if response in self.answer:
    count += self.value
else:
    count -= self.value
print (count)
```

I think I'm having trouble with local/global variables.

Comment: if its a single player thing you could have count as part of the class i.e. `self.count = 0`
or if you want to use global, declare it as global `global count`

Comment: thanks, I think the below method best suits my needs and understanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you call "ask" you are resetting count to 0. Also count is a local variable since it is only defined inside ask(). You need to make count a member of the class and initialize it to 0. Then you can use it like the other class variables. See code below.

```
def __init__(self, question, answer, value):
 self.question = question
 self.answer = answer
 self.value = value
 self.count=0

def ask(self):
 print (self.question + "?")
 response = input().strip()
 if response in self.answer:
    x = random.randint(0,3)
    print (positives[x])
    print ("Answer is" + " " + self.answer)
    self.count += self.value


 ... etc
```

But I am not happy with your logic of including your score inside your question class - because the score relates to numerous questions so it would need to be either globally defined in your class or outside of the class so when you call your method ask it should return whether the answer was true or false or the value, like this

```
 def ask(self):
  print (self.question + "?")
  count = 0
  response = input().strip()
  if response in self.answer:
    x = random.randint(0,3)
    print (positives[x])
    print ("Answer is" + " " + self.answer)
    return self.value
  else:
    y = random.randint(0,3)
    return 0
```

then you do the following;

```
 score=0
 for question in questions:
  print ("Continue?")
  choice = input()
  if choice in ["quit", "no", "exit", "escape", "leave"]:
    break
  score+=question.ask()
```

Comment: So I did it this way

Comment: Hi user32329 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: My pleasure - anytime.